# ViewModel Parameter always DEFAULT values in WebAPI POST

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am having trouble getting my client to send data and my controller accept that data with the values sent.

In the client, I can console.log the values and they appear as they are supposed to.  My PUT (edit item) controller functions perfectly fine using nearly the same logic (except without passing an ID).  I have tried nearly everything I could think of to try to get the POST to show the data I'm passing to it but to no avail.  Am I missing some crucial step?  I've scoured stack overflow and people seem to have similar issues but none of the solutions have worked for me thus far.

```
    [Route("add")]
    public void Post(ItemsViewModel model)
    {
        var item = new Item()
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            Classification = model.Classification,
            DatabaseLink = model.DatabaseLink,
            IsBis = model.IsBis,
            ItemType = model.ItemType,
            Phase = model.Phase,
            PrimaryPrice = model.PrimaryPrice,
            Priority = model.Priority,
            Slot = model.Slot,
            Source = model.Source
        };

        if (item != null)
        {
            _unitOfWork.Items.Add(item);
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

And for the client...

```
 console.log(this.addItemForm.getRawValue());
    this.http.post(`api/items/add`, this.addItemForm.getRawValue()).subscribe(res => {
```

The console reads...

```
id: 0
phase: 1
name: "dasdad"
classification: "dsadad"
source: "qdsadasd"
slot: "dasdasd"
itemType: "sdasdsa"
isBis: true
primaryPrice: "1.112"
priority: "sadasdada"
databaseLink: 12345
```

My Edit Item Controller (PUT) works totally fine, but the Add one does not.

```
this.http.put(`api/items/update/${this.editItemForm.getRawValue().id}`, this.editItemForm.getRawValue()).subscribe(res => {

[Route("update/{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]ItemsViewModel model)
    {
        var item = _unitOfWork.Items.Get(id);

        if (item != null)
        {
            item.Name = model.Name;
            item.Classification = model.Classification;
            item.DatabaseLink = model.DatabaseLink;
            item.IsBis = model.IsBis;
            item.ItemType = model.ItemType;
            item.Phase = model.Phase;
            item.PrimaryPrice = model.PrimaryPrice;
            item.Priority = model.Priority;
            item.Slot = model.Slot;
            item.Source = model.Source;


            _unitOfWork.Items.Update(item);
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

If anyone can help diagnose, please that would be great, been stuck on this for several days now.

**Several things I've tried already... Using [FromBody] turning into into a JSON object, adding a ctor in the model, the viewmodel.  Creating an Item object in the client and passing the web client to the controller that way, and more...  It ALWAYS reaches the controller in a breakpoint, but the model in the parameter no matter what I try, all the data in there is null or default 0.**

**Updated Network Tab View**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get your [post](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request) to work, try setting your http [headers](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers).

```
private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

this.http.post(`api/items/add`, this.addItemForm.getRawValue(), httpOptions)
```

Have a look at the WebApi [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#examine-the-posttodoitem-create-method) for a Post in netcore 3, it may be worth trying to add the `[HttpPost]` attribute to the controller.

If you are still having issues, make sure that the types of you ViewModel match / can be converted from the object that you are passing through your Angular `http.post` call.

Comment: Sadly this does not seem to do anything either, I retried this again, but I have tried it before.

Comment: What version of .Net / WebAPI are you using?

Comment: Also can you see what JSON is being sent from the network tab of your browser, just to check?

Comment: I updated the post with the picture of the network tab on the browser.

Comment: im using Asp.Net Core 3.0.. Honestly not entirely sure where to find the web api version although this is the startup template I'm using currently...
https://www.ebenmonney.com/quickapp-asp-net-core-angular-startup-project-template/

Comment: netcore 3 is enough for me to go on, I'll have a look when I get chance later.